# How to remove a package?

Tags: packages, installing

I know how to install - [Installing Extra Packages](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages). But how to remove?

In particular, package "ifpdf.sty" from the bundle "oberdiek" (or the whole bundle).

System:

- OS: Ubuntu 12.04
- Latex: pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)

**UPDATE**: the original problem why I needed this is resolved. Now the question has a purely theoretic character: "There is a manual on the web how to install a package, but there seems to be none on how to remove".

Comment: Why do you want to remove this package (which is used by a lot of other packages and so removing it is not a good idea)?

Comment: I generally delete the files, and then update the filename database.  I generally only delete stuff though, if I want to force a reload of it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am tracking why my paper does not compile -- this is one of the options to try (remove it and try compiling). Another option -- try removing latex3 bundle.

Comment: The recommended and less invasive way would be to make a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html) and make deleting packages the last resort.

Comment: @Ayrat Well then you should just delete the package loading in your header. Or each package which loads this .sty-file. No need, to literally delete this package from your machine.

Comment: You can create an empty ifpdf.sty in your current folder if you want to test what happens without it. You can also trick latex in thinking that the package has already been loaded by addding `\makeatletter\@namedef{ver@ifpdf.sty}\makeatother` to your document. But I seldom need such tricks for tests.

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys! -- in the end manual removal of `l3kernel` resolved my original problem.

Comment: Whatever the problem is that can't be the correct solution. the l3kernel packages just being installed will do nothing (latex won't load them)  so if they were doing something then you must be using a package that is loading the l3kernel packages. that will break now they are gone unless you previously had 2 installed versions and now you are using the old (or new?) one.

Comment: Regarding the theoretical question: im miktex it can be done with the package manager, in a current texlive with tlmgr. But normally it should not be necessary so you should really check what's going on.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are right -- there were two installations of l3kernel. I removed the manually installed bundle and now the new one is used, nice logic!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer 1) Where did you get `tlmgr`? There is none on my machine. 2) If you put your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: When you did a vanilla install of TeX Live it will be iinstalled. The TeX Live in the repositories of Debian is quite old and there is no tlmgr available. Updateing to a recent version of ubuntu will take care of that.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the theoretical question: in miktex it can be done with the package manager (either the user or the admin version depending on how you did install the package), in a current texlive with tlmgr. But normally it should not be necessary so you should really check what's going on. –