# Index not generated in an Arabic document

Tags: babel, indexing

In the shown MWE, I cannot determine why the index is not generated, although the code is very simple, no room for any conflicts,  I am using LUALATEX to compile the file

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r,layout=counters.lists]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}
\babelfont{rm}{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\chapter{سسسييسسييس}
\section{ مقدمة}
\section{مقدمة عن تاريخ الكتابة المصرية القديمة}
\section{مقدمة عن تاريخ الكتابة المصرية القديمة}
\clearpage
\section{مقدمة عن تاريخ الكتابة المصرية القديمة}
. حيث حُذِفَت علامة الرفع (وس) وايضاً حُذِفَت الحركة الأولى (أي) والتي ظنها العرب استهلال يتبقى اسم قبط
\index{شبيسبسي}
\index{سيبسيبسي}
وهى مأخوذة من "حام" بن نوح
سيبيسبيسبسيب
سيبيسبيسبسيب
بيلبيلبيلبيلبيلبيل 
\newpage
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might be able to get  help faster if you only used fonts that are available with LaTeX it self. I don't have times new roman. But it compiles without it. Did you look in the log of the compilation, mine says `Scanning input file imf.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 2 rejected).` meaning that makeindex rejected the two arabic entries, which is expected as it does not know utf8.

Comment: babel inject something in the idx that makeindex doesn't like. But even if one correct this: I don't see how an 8bit application like makeindex should be able to sort arabic indexentries. You should better check alternatives like bib2gls, xindex or xindy (but I have no idea if they can handle RTL. Or add sortkeys manually.

Comment: @Ulrike, I tried xindy and it did not work

Comment: @daleif actually makeindex doesn't stumble over the arabic but over the format of the number (babel injects something there).

Comment: xindy is only my third suggestion - I would try bib2gls first. As it is java based it contains some unicode libraries for sorting.

Comment: @Ulrike, do you happen to have any link explaining on how to use such package

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I noticed

Comment: Try without the option `counters`.

Comment: @Javier, I need the option counter to have section numbering in the Main language which is Arabic

Comment: But does the index work without it? If it does I could devise a workaround.

Comment: @Javier, Nope problem is still not resolved

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Also Glossaries are not working, so using bib2gls won't work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506459/glossaries-in-multilingual-document

Comment: I wrote bib2gls not simply glossaries. Did you that?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, bib2gls.sty not found, can you post a MWE?

Comment: I'm not sure the entries are sorted correctly, but without `counters` it works for me and the index is generated and shown -- `Scanning input file xxx.idx....done (2 entries accepted, 0 rejected)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example of creating index on arabic document with `context`, it is availible on texlive so if you are using miktex you need to change it to texlive.

The first run of context will take a while, you can use `texworks` which provides option for context compilation

More about indexing on context https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Registers

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\mainlanguage[ar] 
\setupdirections[bidi=global,method=one]
\setupalign[r2l] 

\definefontfamily [myfont][serif][Amiri]   [features=arabic]
\setupbodyfont [myfont]

\setupmixedcolumns[register][direction=reverse]

\starttext

اللُّغَة العَرَبِيّة هي أكثر اللغات تحدثاً ونطقاً ضمن مجموعة اللغات السامية، وإحدى أكثر 
اللغات انتشاراً في العالم، يتحدثها أكثر من 467 مليون نسمة، ويتوزع متحدثوها في 
الوطن العربي،
 \index{بسم }
 بسم 
\index{نص}
 نص
 \index{أبجد} 
 أبجد
 \index{جسد} 
 جسد

\completeindex

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I currently cannot change the main aspects of my code, do you happen to have a solution for my case where I am using babel package and biblatex where I compile the file with LUALATEX

Comment: No I have no solution with babel (lualatex),  there is `xindy-persian` but I never used it.

Answer (score 3):

both biber and bib2gls can sort arabic. I can't read the script, so I have no idea if the sorting is done correctly.

## Example for bib2gls

Compile with

```
  lualatex file
  bib2gls file
  lualatex file

\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{filecontents} %uncomment to oeverwrite the bib

\begin{filecontents}{arabindex.bib}
% Encoding: UTF-8
@entry{A,
  name = {أبجد},
  description = {Alphabetize}}

@entry{B,
  name = {بسملسامية},
  description = {nonsense}}

@entry{X,
  name = {سملسامية},
  description = {nonsense2}}  
@entry{I,
  name = {بسم},
  description = {In nomine Domini}}        
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[bidi=basic-r,layout=counters.lists]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}

\usepackage[record=only]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[selection={all},%
            src={arabindex},%
            sort={ar},
            sort-field={name},
            charset=UTF-8,%
            ]
\begin{document}

\gls{B}, \gls{I} \gls{A} \gls{X}

\printunsrtglossaries 

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Example for biber

Compile with

```
  lualatex file
  biber file
  lualatex file
```

This shows only the principle, to be usable as index one would have to add some more entry types and fields and adapt the drivers.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{arabbiblatex.bib}
% Encoding: UTF-8
@article{A,
  author = {أبجد},
  title = {Alphabetize}}

@article{B,
  author = {بسملسامية},
  title = {nonsense}}

@article{X,
  author = {سملسامية},
  title = {nonsense2}}
@article{I,
  author = {بسم},
  title = {In nomine Domini}}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[bidi=basic-r,layout=counters.lists]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{arabbiblatex.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Ulrike, i still get the error : Undefined control sequence : \ForEachTrackedDialec

Comment: is your tex system up-to-date?

Comment: I am using texlive 2019

Comment: then upload the log-file of **my** example somewhere. then I can compare.

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/96fgr5jhjvwjk77/bib2gls.log/file

Comment: THis is the log file for the bib2gls file example

Comment: I have a number of newer packages, most importantly my babel is newer. Check for updates.

Comment: I did update the packages, they were outdated, but still the same issue persists, here is the log file after compiling with the updated packages: https://www.mediafire.com/file/96fgr5jhjvwjk77/bib2gls.log/file

Comment: Hm, something is broken with your tracklang.sty it doesn't input tracklang.tex. Try to deinstall and reinstall the tracklang package.

Comment: Other packages rely on it, have an idea how to remove it since tlmgr does not want to remove it. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215339/how-to-remove-a-package

Comment: I get this message "not removing tracklang, needed by collection-plaingeneric"

Comment: you can always force tlmgr to do something. See the documentation https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html

Comment: I forcibly removed the package and reinstalled it, upon compiling, the file ran with no errors, however, nothing apears in the index and a bunch of questions marks are there, I attached the log file and the pdf file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/sxrjvbu20g8owtt/Desktop.rar/file

Comment: Did you run bib2gls after running lualatex and then lualatex again? bib2gls is an application.

Comment: Sorry for the annoyance, I did not know that, from where do you run it, does it have a different name as an application?

Comment: Also regarding the example with "Biber", I do know how to run biber, however, you mentioned that "to be usable as index one would have to add some more entry types and fields and adapt the drivers." What is meant by drivers, can such method be used t generate an index with (\index{dfdf}) or is it only for authors and references?

Comment: Open a command line and run "bib2gls name-of-your-file". You can fake with biber an index - there are lots of similarities between index and bibliography - but imho bib2gls and glossaries would be less work. I only tried with biber as I wanted to see how well it sorts such a script.

Comment: THX, ISSUE FINALLY RESOLVED

Comment: @ Ulrike, the [Xindex] package worked after I made the update, so now I can use [Xindex] for indexing and [bib2gls] for glossary. THX for your help

Comment: the index is generated withing the above file only upon removing the option (layout=counters.lists)  from the babel package. Do you happen to have any workarounds since such option is necessary for the numbering to appear with the main document language, it is strange that the index in sch case is generated with any of the index packages, even the most trivial ones. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507066/index-conflict-with-babel-package

Comment: Regarding the above solution, can I add cross-references and citations to the glossary. Also it has issues reading the greek text. In addition, can it be automatically set to right align rtl text and vice versa?